# 24.04 updates - how does it work?

Tags: apt, upgrade, 24.04

I need to build a new server. To avoid a distribution upgrade in a few weeks I was considering installing a pre release version of 24.04. I have a couple of questions though. Will I be able to use the built in package managers (apt, snap) to update it? Will this keep it in line with the daily releases?
And when it is properly released next month will this just update from the pre release version?

Comment: Ubuntu 24.04 (*noble*) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *noble* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 18 April 2024, and isn't on-topic here until release on 25 April 2024.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-schedule/35649  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *noble* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"*Will I be able to use the built in package managers (apt, snap) to update it?*"

Yes.

"*Will this keep it in line with the daily releases?*"

Yes.

"*And when it is properly released next month will this just update from the pre release version?*"

Yes.

Keep in mind that AskUbuntu does not provide support for pre-release software. We will begin answering questions about 24.04 after release.